# I've got a error saying network error and axios error

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I'm getting a **network error** problem in the console. I tried putting the **cors** above routes but still it didn't work.

[image]

Here's some of my code!
I connected the backend and the frontend  by middleware and hence when i tried to create a new post, I got the error. I tried debugging it  by putting my route imports below the **cors** but still im getting the network error. Help!

**server index.js file**

```
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import cors from 'cors';

import postRoutes from './routes/posts.js';

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "30mb", extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "30mb", extended: true}));
app.unsubscribe(cors());

app.use('/posts', postRoutes);
```

**api**

```
import axios from 'axios';

const url = 'http://localhost:5000/posts';

export const fetchPosts = () => axios.get(url);

export const createPost = (newPost) => axios.post(url, newPost);
```

**post.js file**

```
import * as api from '../api';

// Action creators

export const getPosts = () => async (dispatch) => {

    try {
        const { data } = await api.fetchPosts();

        dispatch({type: 'FETCH_ALL', payload: data });
    } catch (error) {
         console.log(error.message);
    }

    // const action = { type: 'FETCH_ALL', payload: [] }


}

export const createPost = (post) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        const {data} = await api.createPost();

        dispatch({ type:'CREATE', payload: data})
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try to replace this:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "30mb", extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "30mb", extended: true}));
app.unsubscribe(cors());
```

with this:

```
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "30mb", extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "30mb", extended: true}));
```

(change `unsubscribe` with `use` and put it before `bodyParser`)